# Paypal IOS SDK + remove phone tab

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

I use Paypal SDK for IOS. But I just want login Paypal by email.
Can I remove tab "Phone" in PaypalViewController?

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible. If you are planning to use [PayPal-iOS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) Than this can not be done.

You can see customisation option in [PayPalConfiguration.h](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/PayPalMobile/PayPalConfiguration.h) file. You can provide default email or Phone number but you can not remove any option.

If this is very very important requirement than you have to go for [PayPal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/). I don't suggest to go for this without any Important reason.